# Change column matrix in a matrix into a block matrix

Tags: formatting, matrices, nicematrix

Can any one help me with changing the column `(a43,a53,a63,a73)` to be a block `$I_n$` and `(a44,a54,a64,a74)` to be a block `$0_{N \times n}$` ?
[image]

Here is the code for this version:

```
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    -I_{n} & \mathbf{0}_{n} & \mathbf{0}_{n \times N} & -I_{n} \\
    I_{n} & \mathbf{0}_{n} & \mathbf{0}_{n \times N} & -I_{n} \\
    \mathbf{0}_{N \times n} & \mathbf{0}_{N} & -I_{N} & \mathbf{0}_{N \times n} \\
    -y_1x_1^T & -y_1 & a_{43} & a_{44} \\
    -y_2x_2^T & -y_2 & a_{53} & a_{54} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & a_{63} & a_{64} \\
    -y_Nx_N^T & -y_N  & a_{73} & a_{74}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

The desired matrix is like this
[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Thanks for improving your post. However, a few lines are missing which a) would enable a compile when copied, b) avoids guessing. I.e start with \documentclass and end with \end{document} . Thank you

Comment: Do you want a sub-matrix? Is that what a `block` means?

Comment: @cfr I don't know that we are on the same page or not, but I edit the post to show you the desired matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really just a question of reading the documentation for the packages you already tagged ...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713991/
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{bNiceArray}{cc:ccc}
  -I_{n} & \mathbf{0}_{n} & \mathbf{0}_{n \times N} && -I_{n} \\
  I_{n} & \mathbf{0}_{n} & \mathbf{0}_{n \times N} && -I_{n} \\
  \mathbf{0}_{N \times n} & \mathbf{0}_{N} & -I_{N} && \mathbf{0}_{N \times n} \\ \hdottedline
  -y_1x_1^T & -y_1 & \Block{4-1}{I_N} & \Vdotsfor{4} & \Block{4-1}{\mathbf{0}_{N \times n}} \\
  -y_2x_2^T & -y_2 &  &&  \\
  \vdots & \vdots &  &&  \\
  -y_Nx_N^T & -y_N  &  && 
\end{bNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

Pretty sure you can get dashed rules if you search the docs for `dashed`.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a screenshot.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. The bug is a pain. I suppose I should find a new PDF viewer ....